# How to indicate any color by colorpicker indicator itself?

Tags: java, android, color-picker

My situation
image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS12w.jpg)

I am using a library of color picker which have an image and the indicator(showing current color) on view.I am saving few color on imageview background.it get saved .all going good.

But now i want that when i click on imageview(in which i saved the background color),indicator of color picker itself move on that color which i previously saved in imageview.How i can achieve it??

Comment: We don't know what library you use, but maybe there is an option in your library to initialize the colorpicker with a color

Comment: i am using it 'com.github.skydoves:colorpickerview:1.0.0',now plz help me out